# The advice on the simplification of the functions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, crud

I have an entity `Contracts` like this:

```
public partial class Contracts
{
    public Contracts()
    {
        ListKindWorks = new HashSet<ListKindWorks>();
        ListSubjects = new HashSet<ListSubjects>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Num { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateConclusion { get; set; }
    public int Worker { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateStartWork { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateEndWork { get; set; }
    public float Salary { get; set; }

    public virtual Workers WorkerNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ListKindWorks> ListKindWorks { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ListSubjects> ListSubjects { get; set; }   
}
```

And function `ShowUpdateDialog()`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Open dialog for update chosen Contract
/// </summary>
/// <param name="c">chosen Contract</param>
internal void ShowUpdateDialog(Contracts c)
{
    Contract = c;
    using (ContractForm form = new ContractForm())
    {
        form.Fill(model.Data);
        form.Fill(Contract);
        form.Fill(model.GetUI(Mode.UPDATE));
        if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            bool result = true;
            try
            {
                using (ModelContext context = new ModelContext())
                {
                    context.Attach(Contract);
                    Contract = form.GetMainValues(Contract);
                    Contract = form.GetDetailValues(Contract);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result = false;
                string msg = string.Format("Ошибка во время обновления записи в базе данных. Детали: {0}", ex.Message);
                form.ShowError(msg);
            }

            if (result)
            {
                ContractUpdatedSuccessEvent?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

External variable:

```
public Contracts Contract { get; set; }
```

It is used not to allocate memory every time and is public, so that in case of a successful update another class can take it and insert into the DataGridView. Therefore I'm not accessing the database for the current values of the record, because the data comes from the DataGridView. To track changes used `context.Attach(Contract)`.

```
internal Contracts GetMainValues(Contracts c)
{
    c.Num = tbNum.Text;
    c.Salary = float.Parse(tbSalary.Text);
    c.DateConclusion = dpDateConclusion.Value;
    c.DateStartWork = dpDateStart.Value;
    c.DateEndWork = dpDateEnd.Value;
    Item item = (Item)cbWorker.SelectedItem;
    c.Worker = item.Id;

    return c;
}


internal Contracts GetDetailValues(Contracts c)
{
    listKindWorks.Clear();
    listSelectedSubjects.Clear();

    foreach (int index in clbKindWork.CheckedIndices)
    {
        int id = ((Item)clbKindWork.Items[index]).Id;
        ListKindWorks item = new ListKindWorks
        {
            IdContract = c.Id,
            IdKindWork = id
        };
        listKindWorks.Add(item);
    }
    foreach (Item item in lbSelectedSubject.Items)
    {
        ListSubjects subject = new ListSubjects
        {
            IdContract = c.Id,
            IdSubject = item.Id
        };
        listSelectedSubjects.Add(subject);
    }

    c.ListKindWorks = listKindWorks;
    c.ListSubjects = listSelectedSubjects;

    return c;
}
```

**My problem is as follows:**

When `if (.. == DialogResult.OK)` is true, I need to update current `Contract` to new values from a `form` like this:

```
context.Attach(Contract);
Contract = form.GetMainValues(Contract);
Contract = form.GetDetailValues(Contract);
context.SaveChanges();
```

But therefore this code must be into `using (ContractForm..)`. Otherwise impossible to get new values from `form`. If I create a new variable like `Contracts` and separate function `Update` like this:

```
private void Update(Contracts c)
{
    using (ModelContext context = new ModelContext())
    {
        context.Attach(Contract);
        Contract = c;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

No update occurs for values from `GetDetailValues()`. Why?

Can I simplify this code?

**Update:**

According code from answer [Henk Holterman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56883127/11563179) and my `private void Update(Contracts c)`:

changed values from `GetMainValues()`, but no from `GetDetailValues()`

Comment: .Attach attaches the entity in unchanged state, therefore no update will occur. Either set context.Entry(Contract) instead or simply set the entities state to modified.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro Likewise. Without attach, but with `context.Entry(c).State = EntityState.Modified` - changed values from `GetMainValues()`, but no from `GetDetailValues()`

Comment: @DevilSuichiro also doesn't help `context.Entry(c).Collection(x => x.ListKindWorks).IsModified = true`

Comment: .Collection().IsModified means: the collection is changed to different values, but you didn't specify that previously existing entries changed. You have to find out which entries are added, which deleted and which modified, and set the state accordingly.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro see first code after `My problem is as follows`. It is works correctly and simple. And any attempt to separate getting new data and updating it only complicates the whole code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added to `Contracts` method `Update()` and call it after `.Attach()`

```
internal void Update(Contracts c)
{
    this.Num = c.Num;
    this.Salary = c.Salary;
    this.Worker = c.Worker;
    this.FullName = c.FullName;
    this.DateConclusion = c.DateConclusion;
    this.DateStartWork = c.DateStartWork;
    this.DateEndWork = c.DateEndWork;
    this.ListKindWorks = c.ListKindWorks;
    this.ListSubjects = c.ListSubjects;
}

private void Update(Contracts oldValue, Contracts newValue)
{
    using (ModelContext context = new ModelContext())
    {
        context.Attach(oldValue);
        oldValue.Update(newValue);
        // oldValue = newValue; // .Attach does not respond to this
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```